# Child of List<T> vs. BindingList<T> Behaving Differently When Attached to UltraWinGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, relationship, infragistics

I'm trying to create an in-memory representation of my data model.  It is a "Payload" with "Sequences" and "Operations".  A sequence *can* have other sequences below it and each sequence has lists of operations associated with the sequence.

Here is some mock data I am using for testing to give an idea:

```
public static void CreateMockData() //for making a car
{
    //parameters: SequenceNo (int), ParentSequenceNo (int?), SequenceType (enum), Description (string)
    Repository.SequencesList.Add(new Sequence(0, null, SequenceType.Standard, "Car assembly"));
    //parameters: ParentSequenceNo (int), OperationNo (int), Activity (string)
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(0, 100, "Gather body parts"));
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(0, 200, "Gather rims and tires"));

    Repository.SequencesList.Add(new Sequence(1, 0, SequenceType.Alternate, "Wheel assembly"));
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(0, 300, "Mount tires on rims"));
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(0, 400, "Inflate tires"));

    Repository.SequencesList.Add(new Sequence(2, 0, SequenceType.Alternate, "Body assembly"));
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(2, 500, "Paint car body parts"));
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(0, 600, "Bolt body parts to car body"));

    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(0, 700, "Install engine"));
        
    Repository.SequencesList.Add(new Sequence(3, 2, SequenceType.Parallel, "Battery charging and installation"));
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(3, 800, "Charge battery"));
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(3, 900, "Install battery"));

    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(0, 1000, "Bolt wheels to car"));
        
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(0, 1100, "Do final inspection"));
    Repository.OperationsList.Add(new Operation(0, 1200, "Sign off inspection"));
}
```

The "Repository" class acts as a mock db, holding all the possible sequences and operations:

```
public static class Repository //mock db
{
    public static List<Sequence> SequencesList = new List<Sequence>(); //dumb list because it's a mock db, no need for binding stuff
    public static List<Operation> OperationsList = new List<Operation>(); //dumb list because it's a mock db, no need for binding stuff
}
```

Here are the "Sequence" and "Operation" classes

```
public enum SequenceType { Standard = 0, Alternate = 1, Parallel = 2 }

public class Sequence
{
    public Sequence() { }

    public Sequence(int SequenceNo, int? ParentSequenceNo, SequenceType Type, string Description)
    {
        this.SequenceNo = SequenceNo;
        this.ParentSequenceNo = ParentSequenceNo;
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Description = Description;
    }

    private Guid internalID = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid ID { get { return internalID; } }
    public int SequenceNo { get; set; }
    public int? ParentSequenceNo { get; set; } //if this is the main sequence then null, all others have a parent
    public SequenceType Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? BranchOperation { get; set; }
    public int? ReturnOperation { get; set; }

    //children
    //part of the problem here
    //if i change either of these list types to BindingList<T> they keep getting called over and over after binding to the grid...

    //public BindingList<Sequence> SubSequences { get { return Repository.SequencesList.FindAll(x => x.ParentSequenceNo == this.SequenceNo).ToBindingList(); }}
    //above will get called over and over...
    public List<Sequence> SubSequences { get { return Repository.SequencesList.FindAll(x => x.ParentSequenceNo == this.SequenceNo); } } 
    public List<Operation> Operations { get { return Repository.OperationsList.FindAll(x => x.ParentSequenceNo == this.SequenceNo); } }

    public void Save()
    {
        Repository.SequencesList[Repository.SequencesList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == this.ID)] = this;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        Repository.SequencesList[Repository.SequencesList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == this.ID)].Delete();
    }
}

public class Operation
{
    public Operation() { }

    public Operation(int ParentSequenceNo, int OperationNumber, string Activity) 
    {
        this.ParentSequenceNo = ParentSequenceNo;
        this.Activity = Activity;
    }

    private Guid internalID = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid ID { get { return internalID; } }
    public int ParentSequenceNo { get; set; }
    public int OperationNumber { get; set; }
    public string Activity { get; set; }
    public string OperationText { get; set; }
    public double LaborHours { get; set; } = 0;

    public void Save()
    {
        Repository.OperationsList[Repository.OperationsList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == this.ID)] = this;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        Repository.OperationsList[Repository.OperationsList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == this.ID)].Delete();
    }
}
```

**The problem(s)...**

I am using an Infragistics UltraWinGrid control.

1. When I use a `List<T>` data type for the Sequence child lists, things work as I would expect, however, of the child bands (which are two different types, `List<Sequence>` and `List<Operation>`), only the columns for Sequence are shown. See image..
2. When I use a `BindingList<T>` type for the child lists, they child binding lists keep getting called over and over just eating up the memory and the program never starts.  This doesn't happen with a `List<T>` type.

Binding the list to the grid:

```
private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MockDataFiller.CreateMockData();
    List<Sequence> zeroSequenceList = new List<Sequence>();
    zeroSequenceList.Add(Repository.SequencesList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SequenceNo == 0));
    gridSequences.DataSource = zeroSequenceList;
}
```

Example of bound grid with List (for Problem #1):
[image]

My ultimate goal is to get this working with a BindingList (Problem 2) but, I'm really lost here.  Any help to point me in the correct direction will be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to limit the `MaxBandDepth` property to `3`. Before setting the `DataSource` define  `gridSequences.DisplayLayout.MaxBandDepth = 3;`

Comment: Wow, that actually worked!  I had posted over on the infragistics forums as well and they suggested the same MaxBandDepth setting but, the difference is that you suggested to do it *before* setting the datasource.  Not sure why it makes a difference but, I'm happy that it's working now.  If you post as an answer I can accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gets or sets the max band depth. Grid will load upto ***MaxBandDepth***
> number of bands. Note that you have to set the ***MaxBandDepth*** before
> binding the `UltraGrid`.

**From the Infragistics documentation:**

Use this property to force the grid to load upto only a certain number of bands. This can come in use where you have a ***recursive data relation*** where a table is related to itself and you only want the grid to drill down the band hierarchy only upto a certain level.

Default value for this property is 100 and range is 1-100 inclusive. Throws an ArgumentOutOfRange exception if set to a value below 1 or greater than 100.

***Note: You must set the MaxBandDepth before binding the UltraGrid to a data source in order for this property to have any effect.***

See [MaxBandDepth Property](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragridlayout%7Emaxbanddepth)